# SQL - Summarizing Monthly Sales Data

Tags: sql, counting

I have two tables that I need to combine, but I can't get to seem the joins to work. The picture has three tables

_date_array2: Has a field DateMonthYr that contains all possible date/yr combinations

_sales_summ_tbl__ => Has 5 fields. Only months with sales show up. For example, you see only three records showing up for the second table. There is no 5/2016, for example, because there were no sales for that month.

My goal is to "pad" the second table to have TotalDemand of 0's for months with no sales. I am very close (see the third table), except I cannot get the PartNumber to show up for dates with no sales.

My guess is that it's due to the RIGHT JOIN. But I'm not sure how to handle this. **The output I am hoping for is table 3 but with the part number populated for all entries.**

[image]

And here is my code (the results from running this code are the third/last table in the picture):

```
SELECT TmpSalesTbl.PartNumber as PartNumber,
tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonth as CreateDateMonth,
tmp_date_array.CreateDateYear as CreateDateYear,
CASE WHEN TmpSalesTbl.TotalDemand is NULL THEN 0 ELSE TmpSalesTbl.TotalDemand END as TotalDemand
FROM #_sales_summ_tbl__ TmpSalesTbl
RIGHT JOIN #_date_array2 tmp_date_array on tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonthYr = TmpSalesTbl.CreateDateMonthYr
ORDER BY tmp_date_array.CreateDateYear, tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonth
```

Comment: What is the result from your query?

Comment: The result of my query is the third table in the picture. I'm very stumped so any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: There is no sale so what should be the part number for that month and year?

Comment: My goal for the third table is to have a record with the Part number showing 0 sales.

Comment: Is there just one part number? If you have more than one part number then it will have one row for each part number.

Comment: There is more than one part number - I was just pulling this one as an example.

Comment: So then it is acceptable to have two rows for each month and year combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more conventional to place the list of all dates first, then left join to the data and whilst using a case expression is fine an alternative is `coalesce()`. This should ensure all the wanted months/years display:

```
SELECT
      tmpsalestbl.PartNumber               AS partnumber
    , tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonth       AS createdatemonth
    , tmp_date_array.CreateDateYear        AS createdateyear
    , COALESCE(tmpsalestbl.TotalDemand, 0) AS totaldemand
FROM #_date_array2 tmp_date_array
LEFT JOIN #_sales_summ_tbl__ tmpsalestbl ON tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonthYr = tmpsalestbl.CreateDateMonthYr
ORDER BY
      tmp_date_array.CreateDateYear
    , tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonth
```

To populate for evey partnumber, on every month, you will need a new subquery:

```
select distinct PartNumber #_sales_summ_tbl__
```

And then `cross join` that to the years/months so you have a complete set of years/months/parts.

```
SELECT
      cj.PartNumber                        AS partnumber
    , tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonth       AS createdatemonth
    , tmp_date_array.CreateDateYear        AS createdateyear
    , COALESCE(tmpsalestbl.TotalDemand, 0) AS totaldemand
FROM #_date_array2 tmp_date_array
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            PartNumber FROM #_sales_summ_tbl__
      ) cj
LEFT JOIN #_sales_summ_tbl__ tmpsalestbl ON tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonthYr = tmpsalestbl.CreateDateMonthYr
                                        AND cj.PartNumber = tmpsalestbl.PartNumber
ORDER BY
      tmp_date_array.CreateDateYear
    , tmp_date_array.CreateDateMonth
;
```

Comment: I ran your code but for months with no sales PartNumber is NULL

Comment: I was in the process of editing the remainder, please refresh page

Comment: Basically this DOES display the 15 rows I was hoping for, but the part number only shows up for the 3 rows with sales. I was hoping to see it show up for every row.

Comment: did you refresh the page? there is a second query..... use the second one

Comment: Just refreshed. Trying this out now -  I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @clinomaniac picked out a problem and fixed it (thanks): You should refresh again, the new subquery should **NOT** reference that alias `tmpsalestbl`

Comment: I think we are getting there, but it's throwing an error on the middle chunk of code: select distinct tmpsalestbl.PartNumber #_sales_summ_tbl__